# character class in c++ regex is not working properly

Tags: c++, regex

Below program output is "It is not matching" but ideally it should be "It is matching" ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;
using namespace regex_constants;

int main()

{
    string pattern = "[a]*";
    try {
        regex re(pattern, extended);
        if(regex_match("aaaa", re))
           cout << "It is matching" << endl;
        else
           cout << "It is not matching" << endl; 
    }catch(regex_error &e)
    {
       cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiler? gcc has yet to have support for `regex`

Comment: Does it work if you use the default grammar instead of `extended`?

Comment: Try with `-stdlib=libc++`

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling with Clang

```
clang++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ yourfile.cpp
```

Clang (3.3) supports regexes, GCC doesn't yet.